# Exclude a string in Emacs Regexp

Tags: regular-expressions

Is it possible to create a regexp that excludes a string? For example, I want to create a regexp that accepts a set of strings with `*.*helm.**`except a few ones such as `*helm help*`. It means, `*helm help*` should be excluded. I want this regexp functionality because I set `display-buffer-alist` to position Helm windows where I like it to be:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist `("*.*helm.**"
                                    (display-buffer-in-side-window)
                                    (inhibit-same-window . t)
                                    (window-height . 0.4)))
```

However, doing so would prevent a Helm buffer by default displayed in fullscreen, like `*helm help*` buffer.

Comment: A literal star is with two backslashes before it `\\*`, or enclosed within square brackets `[*]`.  Type `M-x re-builder RET` and experiment a bit with samples in the buffer above.  If you modify your question with a few real real life examples with actual strings you wish to match, I or someone else can take a stab at it.  By placing incorrect regexp in your question, it is difficult to know exactly what you want to match.  The carrot `^` within square brackets negates.

Comment: I mean, I want to exclude a whole string, an exact match, not just any character in any order. Currently [*help] includes `help` itself, while I want to exclude it.

Comment: The following link to a thread entitled **How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame** http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489 specifically deals with the `display-buffer-alist` and it contains  custom functions that handle a variety of different situations.  I have a few different variables with lists of regexp matching certain buffers, and a function that goes through the lists comparing the current buffer to be displayed with those in the list -- different action is taken depending upon the regexp matched.  There is an example function that works out of the box.

Comment: *A regexp cannot exclude, by definition.* (Well, you can exclude characters from a class, as in `[^e]`, but that's really an abbreviation for specifying any char except `e`.) It sounds like you are not looking for a **regexp** that excludes a file, but you are instead looking for *some* way to exclude a file from display or from some other handling. If so, you should edit your question, including the title and the tags, to clarify it. It sounds like your question is really about how to use `display-buffer-alist`.

Comment: @Drew I found my own solution by `defadvice` the `helm-help` function to exclude itself. So, yes, I won't use such regexp in this case since it's not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Emacs Lisp doesn't support lookahead resp. lookbehind assertions.
So a function is needed checking twice - match and not-match.

As `display-buffer-alist` accepts functions as argument, there should be a way to realize it.

Comment: You are right. found my own solution by `defadvice` the `helm-help` function to exclude itself from `display-buffer-alist`. Or rather, more correctly, restoring the original `display-buffer-alist` when it enters `*Helm Help*` buffer.

Comment: Why not use a function as first element for a display-buffer-alist entry that matches all Helm buffers and then filters helm help?  That's the preferable solution in my opinion.  Advices should only be your very last resort!

Comment: @lunaryorn Thank you. Works like charm.

Comment: Actually, it was because my old `defadvice` that it works. I need to find another way.

Comment: It works this time in a simpler way and I updated the answer.

Comment: @TuDo While appreciating your intention, you really should not co-write others answers to this extend. Please file an own answer and restore mine. Schnauf:)

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Sure :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the correct answer to my regexp problem, so I left it there. But to solve my own problem, I found a way to do it: instead of trying to negate specific string in the regexp in my original entry added to `display-buffer-alist` to handle Helm buffers, just add another entry for the case you are trying to exclude. For example, if you want to exclude any Helm help buffer, simply defines another entry for it in `display-buffer-alist`:

```
(defvar helm-display-help-buffer-regexp '("*.*Helm.*Help.**"))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist helm-display-help-buffer-regexp)
```

Note that  must be added after your original Helm entry to handle normal Helm buffers, because the `display-buffer-alist` is scanned from left to right and the one that matches first is selected. This means, before checking all other Helm buffers, we must first check whether the current Helm buffer is a Helm help and if so, use the configuration in `helm-display-help-buffer-regexp`. Otherwise, the configuration for common Helm buffers is used for Helm help buffer and as a result, the help buffer can't be displayed because it requires a full window.

Comment: The stars on each end of the regexp serve no purpose that I am aware of.  They are not *literal* stars, and there is already a catch-all on each end -- i.e., `.*` is the catch-all.

Comment: So, `*` is not a literal star but something else? I only want to include all Helm buffers start with `*` and end with `*`, not everything. I think it works fine, givent that buffers with filenames like `helm.el`, `helm-buffers.el`.. are  opened normally.

Comment: The first comment underneath the original question contains two examples of how to match a *literal* astrisk, and it suggests a built-in library for you to use when writing/testing regexp.